# Usage of r9 register in ARM

Tags: arm, u-boot

I am trying to understand the U-boot source(2014.07). I could see the following code in arch/arm/cpu/armv7/lowlevel_init.S file.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
        ldr     r9, =gdata
#else
        sub     sp, sp, #GD_SIZE
        bic     sp, sp, #7
        mov     r9, sp
#endif
        push    {ip, lr}
        bl      s_init
        pop     {ip, pc}
```

Can you please tell why sp is moved to r9 register - "mov r9, sp"(for SPL build gdata is loaded to r9 register- "ldr r9, =gdata").
Is there any specific use of r9 register, so that we are storing sp value to r9.

Comment: While it normally wouldn't be used as an argument, maybe it is. What's inside s_init? Since this is an open source project, could you also link to the sources?

Comment: The s_init function is setting up plls, mux configuration etc. The s_init is defined @ http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c;h=5f50a1980157d646b1308bf8d98b529009d40d1e;hb=524123a70761110c5cf3ccc5f52f6d4da071b959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general ABI set out by ARM in the [Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/index.html) designates r9 as the "Platform Register":

> A virtual platform may assign any role to this register and must document this usage. For example, it may designate it as the static base (SB) in a position-independent data model, or it may designate it as the thread register (TR) in an environment with thread-local storage. The usage of this register may require that the value held is persistent across all calls. A virtual platform that has no need for such a special register may designate r9 as an additional callee-saved variable register, v6.

In this case, the U-Boot ABI appears to use it for a global data pointer (see also *arch/arm/lib/crt0.S* and *arch/arm/include/asm/global_data.h*), but is perhaps falling short on the "must document this usage" point...

Comment: Thanks, so in "arch/arm/cpu/armv7/lowlevel_init.S" they are using r9 as global data pointer. But i don't think they have used this global data pointer in s_init (defined @ http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/omap-common/hwinit-common.c;h=5f50a1980157d646b1308bf8d98b529009d40d1e;hb=524123a70761110c5cf3ccc5f52f6d4da071b959 ). Again in crt0.S they are doing the same(initialize sp, moving sp to GD_SIZE, store the global data pointer in r9).

Comment: According to a comment in the current code, it looks to be for the benefit of old board-specific low-level init code that wants it (presumably called before `_main`)

Comment: This is correct.  It is also worth noting that u-boot may on occasion change the 'r9' register as it configures memory devices.  So the global data may be mobile.  That is **why** they use 'r9'.  The use changes over time/platform so people should be cautious.  The SPL is a 'loader-loader'; SOC rom code usually sets a stack to limited R/W memory so the SPL uses both stack/data in the same place for the SPL loader-loader.