# How are registers used to specify parameters for the SVC function in ARM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I've seen assembly code where registers R0-R2 specify certain parameters for the SVC function, but don't know if that's always specific to those registers or not. Also, if the parameters are specific to those registers, how can I figure out what valid arguments can be passed to those registers in regards to the SVC function?

I tried searching on Google to see how SVC works and also searched for what is valid to pass into registers as SVC parameters but was not able to find anything.

Comment: The calling convention depends on the OS; kernel code in the SVC handler is going to read the register state left by user-space.  (Usually using one of them as a "call number" to dispatch to a system call function, e.g. ARM Linux uses R7 for that IIRC, with call numbers from asm/unistd.h)

Comment: Perhaps we have not answered here.  You need to state an explicit OS, if you want to know the meaning.  For Linux, parameters are passed in R0-R6.  You can see this by using ['man syscall'](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).  Then each system function documents it's own parameters.  For example, [man write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) use a file descriptor, buffer and size.  As per my answer, the 'system call #" is typically passed in a higher register.  For something like QNX, it may not be as obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The `svc` instruction itself doesn't do much - it switches the CPU into supervisor mode, and jumps to a predefined address: either 0x00000008 or 0xFFFF0008. If there is an operating system running on your computer - it would install one of its functions on those addresses.

The behavior completely depends on the OS. The `svc` instruction leaves all registers intact - so the OS can examine any of them. It can also modify any register, before it gives control back - if it ever returns at all.

You should refer to the documentation of a particular OS to know which registers mean what. Be aware, however, that not all OSes make the `svc` interface public. On those that don't, you are supposed to use a library provided by the OS developers instead. Internally, that library would still use `svc` instruction - but the meaning of the registers may not be documented, and can even change between versions.

Comment: Likewise if you roll your own OS or baremetal solution, you get to use SVC and registers however you like.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that ARM doesn't specify what you must do.  However, R7 is commonly used as explained below.

---

Importantly, you would not want to used banked registers as the SVC handler would not have easy access to them.  Probably pedantic (unless you write a 'FIQ' SVC handler).  However, LR/SP are also banked.

---

Even non-linux systems use R7 commonly.  Earlier variants of ARM Linux SVC/SWI encoded the 'call number' in the instruction (Referred to as OABI (yes, also assumes FPU)).  However, this is bad for many reasons.  You need to read the instruction space (very uncommon) and then you have to 'parse' it from the op-code.

With R7 (or any callee saved register) you can use R0,R1,R2,R3 as per normal ABI as function passing.  The use of R7 (callee saved) make it so you can easily setup dispatch and write implementation in plain 'C'.

Call function (example Linux `exit()` wrapper),

```
 #include <linux/unistd.h>
 static inline void exit(int status)
 {
         asm volatile ("mov      r0, %0\n\t"
                 "mov    r7, %1\n\t"
                 "swi    #7\n\t"
                 : : "r" (status),
                   "Ir" (__NR_exit)
                 : "r0", "r7", "memory");
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use `register int callnum asm ("r7") = __NR_exit;` with an `"r"(callnum)` constraint to get the compiler to put args in registers ahead of an `asm` statement whose only instruction is `swi`, as in an `_exit` wrapper in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358451/arm-inline-asm-exit-system-call-with-value-read-from-memory/37363860#37363860).  In this answer, `swi  #0` is used, which is more common to denote that the instruction 'function number' is not used.

An [example output](https://godbolt.org/z/oMEq1bK1o) from this gives:

```
foo():
        push    {r7}           ; save the syscall register
        mov     r3, #-1        ; put directly in R0.
        mov      r0, r3        ; not needed.
        mov    r7, #1          ; syscall function
        swi    #7              ; The #7 is an 'op-code' example.
                               ; Which would be an 'OABI' way to transfer R7.

        ldr     r7, [sp], #4   ; restore r7
        bx      lr             ; resume (not relevant for exit()).
```

This is an implementation in a typical 'C' library.

Your assembler dispatch handler is at least,

- save user registers (depends on scheduler)
- index 'syscall' table with R7.
- jump to 'C' code.

The handler doesn't need to juggle register as R0,..,R3 are in the correct position.  Many OS features will add functionality.

If you use more than four parameters, they are saved on a different stack.  Typically, extended values are passed in a pointer and typically you are very paranoid about user space pointers (eventually).

So, you don't need to use 'R7', but registers above R4 to R12 are good candidates, if you want to simplify the syscall handler by not juggling data between user and supervisor space.  I think R7 was chosen as the wrapper function may need some scratch registers before calling (in R4,R5,R6) and using R7 will not interfere with this (all stored in stack slot from user space).  So, R4 would be the worst choice in this respect.  Also some systems use R10 and even R9 for other purposes ([static base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477570/usage-of-r9-register-in-arm) and [stack limits](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0056/d/using-the-procedure-call-standard/stack-limit-checking/register-usage-with-stack-limit-checking)).  R11 is the 'frame pointer' and R12 is the 'ip' (inter-procedure register).  Some ancient versions of thumb had trouble accessing above R7.  Otherwise, I don't know why R8 would not have been chosen.

Stack limits are fairly rare so R10 would be a good choice, if you defy convention.

Comment: `exit` is a tricky example because it's `noreturn` so register clobbers don't actually matter, but any visible side-effects (like a store to a memory-mapped file) must be done first.  So the clobber list should actually be just `"memory"`.  Or follow it with `__builtin_unreachable()` as documented in the GCC manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels) for asm statements where execution doesn't come out the bottom but you're not jumping within the same function.  Many other system calls (like `write`, `read`, `munmap`) should use a `"memory"` clobber.

Comment: Yes, it is much more complex to implement actual system calls.  I was just meaning to show that the 'exit' parameter 'status' remains in the same register.  I guess the ['vdso'](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) should be mentioned as an alternative to syscalls.  Ie, some information page, read-only, that all processes can see/access.

Comment: Maybe you missed my point here: we could construct an example where GCC will optimize around this inline function in ways that make the program behaviour observably different from calling `_exit()` or `exit_group()` the normal way.  e.g. `mmap_region[0] = 1; asm_exit(); mmap_region[0] = 2;` - dead-store elimination will remove the store before the exit, so nothing is stored.  Or it will store `2` before the exit.  Your `exit` asm needs a `"memory"` clobber or `__builtin_unreachable()` to make it safe and correct.

Comment: Or assignment to a normal array or variable before exiting a thread with this.  Again, a visible side-effect that doesn't need to be `volatile` for correctness so isn't ordered ahead of the asm statement at compile time.  (That `__NR_exit` system call number is [only used by `pthread_exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit); glibc `_exit()` uses `__NR_exit_group` to exit all threads in case there are more than one.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xvss6zxoc is a version with `register int status_r0 asm("r0")` and so on which avoids an extra register even for runtime-variable function args.  But even just an `"Ir"` constraint for `status` helps with your version's test caller with a constant arg, which is a common case.  I also tried `__builtin_unreachable()` to see how that avoids wasting code on restoring r7, although it still pushes it.